# C# Selenium program and Chrome View Source not seeing HTML that matches what I see on the webpage

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use C# and the Selenium library to screen scrape a Service-NOW web page that searches for people by name.  I successfully navigate to the URL and the screen displays the search text box when I intend to enter the person's name, there is no search button; the search is initiated by hitting the ENTER key after entering a person's name.

My issue is that the HTML source doesn't seem to represent what I see on the screen even though I intend to wait until the DOM has been fully loaded. In the example below, I get the HTML for the web page and save it to the file `junk.html`. This appears to match what I see when I select the Chrome menu right mouse option "View page source".

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

string url = "https://mycompany.service-now.com/now/nav/ui/classic/params/target/sys_user_list.do%3Fsysparm_userpref_module%3D555aed3fc0a8016600657c7b0ddc6e97%26sysparm_clear_stack%3Dtrue";
      
// Navigate to the URL
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(160));
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

string htmlSource = driver.PageSource;

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\save\junk.html", htmlSource);
```

I realize that JavaScript can do magical stuff like updating the DOM. I was hoping that if I waited for the DOM to be fully loaded, I would see that it the HTML but I am not finding the search text box nor a default unfiltered search result that gets displayed in a table below the search name textbox.

The HTML source that I do see looks like follows, in case it helps you to help me, although I replace long JSON strings that included lots of HEX strings. The source is mumbo jumbo to me.

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link data-source-id="glide-theme" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/$uxappimmutables.do?sysparm_request_type=ux_theme&amp;sysparm_app_config_sys_id=e42a5af4c700201072b211d4d8c2607c&amp;sysparm_app_sys_id=c86a62e2c7022010099a308dc7c26022&amp;sysparm_page_registry=a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7&amp;uxpcb=sjLZ9B7oiPiaA4Mb3ZGwU1I53Z4=">
  <script async="" type="text/javascript">
    try {
      window.__initialRoutePayload = JSON.parse('{\n  \x22context\x22 : {\n    \x22experienceName\x22 : \x22Unified Navigation App\x22,\n    \x22path\x22 : \x22now\/nav\/ui\x22\n  },\n  \x22fields\x22 : { },\n  \x22params\x22 : {\n    \x22target\x22 : \x22sys_user_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=555aed3fc0a8016600657c7b0ddc6e97\x26sysparm_clear_stack=true\x22\n  },\n  \x22route\x22 : \x22classic\x22\n}');
    } catch (e) { window.__initialRoutePayload = {} }
    if (window && (window != window.top) && (frameElement && frameElement.id != 'testFrame')) {
      if (!window.top.frameBusterRouteChangeWithoutRedirect || !window.top.frameBusterRouteChangeWithoutRedirect(window.__initialRoutePayload))
        window.top.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
  </script>

  <script defer=""
    src="/$uxappimmutables.do?sysparm_request_type=ux_globals_partial&amp;sysparm_page_registry=a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7&amp;uxpcb=L2YBjcnDKdXPFcwleGb8snXS2U4="></script>
  <script defer="" src="/uxsp/all.jsdbx?uxpcb=IgAcNY8UuEv4PppNJtZ+lqBNR1g="></script>
  <script type="module" src="/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/library-uxf/index.jsdbx"></script>

  <title>Users | ServiceNow</title>
  <link href="favicon.ico?v=4" rel="shortcut icon">
  <base href="/" data-sn-href="/now/nav/ui">
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1.42857;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .sn-tooltip {
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      border-radius: 2px;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      display: -webkit-inline-box;
      display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
      display: inline-flex;
      font: 12px "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      height: auto;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 320px;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1070;
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      white-space: normal;
      left: 0;
      top: 0
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => registration.active.postMessage({
      action: 'sendAssetManifest',
      cacheBuster: 1689584504617,
      isUpgrading: false,
      assets: ["cuid/latest/index", "fflate/latest/index", "js-common-mega/bundled-assets", "sn-canvas-core-addon/latest/index", "amb-client-js/index", "@servicenow/ui-mega/index", "sn-canvas-common/latest/index", "sn-canvas-blank/index", "path-to-regexp/latest/index", "@devsnc/library-uxf/index", "sn-canvas-core/index", "dompurify/latest/index", "date-fns/latest/index", "nds-megabundle/bundled-assets", "sn-search-input-wrapper/index", "polaris-app-shell/index", "@devsnc/ux-metrics/index", "sn-canvas-chrome/index", "@devsnc/sn-layout/index", "@servicenow/now-uxf-page/index"],
    }));
  </script>
  <script type="module"> // bootstrapper
    window.uxf.templateLoader.seedPageFragment(JSON.parse("Lots of hex string stuff goes here"));

    window.uxf.templateLoader.seedPageFragment(JSON.parse("Lots of hex string stuff goes here"));
    window.uxf.templateLoader.loadSeededPageFragment('f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010');

    window.uxf.templateLoader.loadSeededPageFragment('76a83a645b122010b913030a1d81c780');
    window.uxf.templateLoader.seedPageFragment(JSON.parse("Lots of hex string stuff goes here"));
    window.uxf.templateLoader.signalSeedingComplete();

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/uxasset/externals/service-worker/loader.jsdbx?uxpcb=1689584504617"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG = { disabled: false, serviceWorkers: [{ "scope": "/", "serviceWorkerUrl": "/uxsw/scope/root.js" }, { "scope": "/x/", "serviceWorkerUrl": "/uxsw/scope/now_x.js" }, { "scope": "/now/", "serviceWorkerUrl": "/uxsw/scope/now_x.js" }] }; if (window.serviceWorkerManager) window.serviceWorkerManager.init(SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG); navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => registration.active.postMessage({
      action: 'setConfig',
      enabledSourceMaps: false,
    }));
  </script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/cuid/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/fflate/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/js-common-mega/bundled-assets.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-canvas-core-addon/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/amb-client-js/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/@servicenow/ui-mega/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-canvas-common/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-canvas-blank/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/path-to-regexp/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/library-uxf/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-canvas-core/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/dompurify/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/date-fns/latest/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/nds-megabundle/bundled-assets.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-search-input-wrapper/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/polaris-app-shell/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/ux-metrics/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/sn-canvas-chrome/index.jsdbx">
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/sn-layout/index.jsdbx">
  <script src="/polaris-ui16-dependencies.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/uxasset/externals/@servicenow/now-uxf-page/index.jsdbx">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>

  <macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010 component-id="czbdqbk" macroponent-namespace="czbdqbk"
    app-id="a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7" global-navigation-config="{
  &quot;features&quot;: {
    &quot;record&quot;: {
      &quot;_default&quot;: {
        &quot;experiencePriorityList&quot;: [
        ]
      }
    },
    &quot;list&quot;: {
      &quot;_default&quot;: {
        &quot;experiencePriorityList&quot;: [
          {
            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Polaris App&quot;,
            &quot;sysId&quot;: &quot;a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7&quot;
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    &quot;search&quot;: {
      &quot;_default&quot;: {
        &quot;experiencePriorityList&quot;: [
          {
            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Polaris App&quot;,
            &quot;sysId&quot;: &quot;a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7&quot;
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    &quot;inbox&quot;:{
      &quot;_default&quot;: {
        &quot;experiencePriorityList&quot;: [
          {
            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Service Operations Workspace&quot;,
            &quot;sysId&quot;: &quot;aa881cad73c4301045216238edf6a716&quot;
          },
          {
            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;CSM/FSM Configurable Workspace&quot;,
            &quot;sysId&quot;: &quot;c4e321a3530210102c30ddeeff7b12f6&quot;
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}" evaluated-data-brokers="{&quot;polaris_user_settings_access_query&quot;:[{&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;executionResult&quot;:{&quot;output&quot;:{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;GlideUserSettingsAccess_Query&quot;:{&quot;userSettingsAccess&quot;:{&quot;showApplicationPicker&quot;:false,&quot;showUpdateSetPicker&quot;:false,&quot;showDomainPicker&quot;:false,&quot;showEncryptionPicker&quot;:false,&quot;showCryptoModulePicker&quot;:false}}}}},&quot;executionTime&quot;:10,&quot;parentResourceId&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:200,&quot;sysId&quot;:&quot;79c9fd62c7113010099a308dc7c260f1&quot;}],&quot;polaris_app_shell_header_logo_target&quot;:[{&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;executionResult&quot;:{&quot;output&quot;:{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;GlideHeaderLogo_Query&quot;:{&quot;getLogoURL&quot;:{&quot;external&quot;:false,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;gsft_main&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;home.do&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}}}}},&quot;executionTime&quot;:0,&quot;parentResourceId&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:200,&quot;sysId&quot;:&quot;b67e4b90c7003010099a308dc7c26094&quot;}]}"
    now-id="czbdqbk"></macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.g_ck = '21b80dda97c8fd5c826135f6f053aff48d6f1e35966d38bd4e1bdc5fb5459e79de5562f6';
    window.transaction_source = 'Interface=Web,Interface-Type=UXF Experience,Interface-Name=Unified Navigation App,Interface-SysID=a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7';
    window.pageMeta = { pageRegistryId: 'a84adaf4c700201072b211d4d8c260b7', pageMacroponentId: 'f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010' };
    window.NOW = window.NOW || {};
    window.NOW.httpRequestCompressionThreshold = 40000;
    window.NOW.httpRequestCompressionLevel = -1;
    window.NOW.httpRequestCompressionMemoryLevel = -1;
    window.NOW.deferAmbConnection = false;
    window.NOW.deferredAmbConnectionTimeout = 10000;
    window.NOW.user = {
      "userID": "ed8bb57adb184c90b47d54f9489619cc",
      "isImpersonating": false
    };
    window.nowUiFramework = {
      "performanceMonitoringEnabled": true,
      "disableRestBatching": false
    };
    window.__TRANSLATIONS__ = {}; (function () {
      var uxGlobals = {};
      uxGlobals.documentServedByGlide = true;
      uxGlobals.documentSupportsMultipleExperiences = true;
      uxGlobals.pageFragmentPartialContentCacheEnabled = true;
      uxGlobals.componentDriverClientCacheBuster = '220RFXEqmHgOU7ZVkVzsdy/ZsuQ=';
      uxGlobals.loginRedirectUrl = "";
      uxGlobals.isLoggedIn = "true";
      uxGlobals.presource = {};
      uxGlobals.sysprops = {};
      uxGlobals.userPrefs = {};
      uxGlobals.session = JSON.parse('Lots of hex string stuff goes here');
      window.__uxfUxGlobalsSketch = uxGlobals;
    }()); document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const CONFIG = { "subscribers": [{ "path": "/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/ux-metrics-client-interaction-subscriber/index.jsdbx" }, { "path": "/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/ux-metrics-appsee-subscriber/index.jsdbx", "config": { "apiAuth": "053e6156f8f5422192b03023a24a7740", "apiKey": "00c3adab6f545e00869e7b2f5d3ee4dd:635911e2732130107d804c9885f6a78f", "endpointURL": "https://api-appsee.service-now.com", "restrictedApps": "", "allowedPropsInPageNavigate": "Entry Page,Page Title", "enableUnauthenticatedUserTracking": "false", "channelType": "NextExperience", "trackingConsent": "Full", "user": { "domainName": "global", "roles": "problem_task_analyst,template_editor,cmdb_ms_editor,u_monitoring_info_user,sn_publications_recipients_user,rota_manager,report_group,viz_creator,app_service_user,service_viewer,cmdb_ms_user,workspace_user,cmdb_query_builder_read,sn_cmdb_user,sn_comm_management.comm_plan_viewer,knowledge,actsub_user,email_client_template_read,template_editor_group,pa_viewer,sn_sow.sow_user,assignment_rule_admin,snc_internal,sn_sttrm_condition_read,cmdb_query_builder,email_composer,certification,agent_workspace_user,canvas_user,sn_publications_recipients_list_user,template_read_global,interaction_agent,data_manager_user,report_user,notify_view,tracked_file_reader,sn_cmdb_editor,restricted_data_user,cmdb_read,dependency_views,itil", "hashId": "ba3e9b32938a7eef4003fbe8e5d2977ec75b3fb0ecf3cb02e3bf245358ace908", "domainId": "global" }, "enabled": "true" } }], "userConsentRequired": false, "globalMetricsLevel": 4 };
      import("/uxasset/externals/@devsnc/ux-metrics-runtime/index.jsdbx")
        .then(runtime => runtime.init(CONFIG))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    });
    window.NOW_UCM_INFO = { "user_consent": "NoConsentRequired", "user_analytics_consent_text": "" };
    window.nowUiFramework = window.nowUiFramework || {};
    window.nowUiFramework.metrics = window.nowUiFramework.metrics || {};
    window.nowUiFramework.metrics.uxPageProcessorTime = 152;
    window.nowUiFramework.metrics.transactionNumber = 36325908;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I was hoping to find the search text box by ID, entering a name and then simulating typing an ENTER key but as mentioned above, Selenium is not seeing the text box not am I seeing it in the HTML source in eiether Chrome or in the HTML file saved in the code above.

```
IWebElement textBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));

textBox.SendKeys("My Name");
```

What can I try next?

### Update

I tried various waits. For example the following waits 100 seconds and then tells me that it can't find any input elements on the page.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));

IWebElement textbox;
textbox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input")));
```

When I select the text box used to search for a person's name in Edge's Developer tools, I see the following HTML:

```
<input type="search" id="19d477be97087ddc826135f6f053af6b_text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" name="19d477be97087ddc826135f6f053af6b_text" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="19d477be97087ddc826135f6f053af6b_describedby">
```

Comment: right-click and choose "Inspect".  That'll open the dev-tools in the browser which will show the current DOM.  Do not check readystate... instead use proper webdriverwaits.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the reply. Yes, I do see an INPUT element in the DOM in Dev Tools but I'm looking to have Selenium see it.  See my update where I wait up to 100 seconds looking for any INPUT element. Selenium never sees it even though it waits 100 seconds before reporting the error.

Comment: you may want to include the markup in your post...  could be the INPUT element is in an iframe, or that it doesn't exist until something else happens... etc... etc...

Comment: I already did include the markup. There is no IFRAME or INPUT element.

Comment: the markup from Inspector... that'll be the current DOM where you are seeing the <input>...  you can copy/paste from there.  Selenium will be working with the DOM that you see in inspector.

Comment: @pcalkins I added the markup that I saw when I inspected the text box that I wanted Selenium to interact with. Note that the ID and the NAME changes every time I go to the page, so I tried other selectors, such as search for all input elements but nothing worked.

Comment: is "ExpectedConditions.ElementExists" a C# thing?  That doesn't seem to be standard... just to rule out the wait/until stuff, add a sleep and then get the element without using a wait.  (try/catch the findElement call...) If you still get an exception you'll want to post the full markup of the DOM... maybe that'll shed some light on the issue.

Comment: ExpectedConditions.ElementExists is functionality provided via the Nuget package DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

Comment: it's sort of odd in that a standard webdriverwait already ignores a "no such element" exception until the wait period is up.   There are going to be various things to check for here... one would be if this is in shadowDOM.  The other is to see if this input is populated after a certain action occurs.